# How do I select an input nested in a td, classname and id name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the id name of the `tr` (rhel6-x86_64), is there a way to select the `<input>` with class name "dependency-tag"? I tried `$('#rhel6-x86_64 td .dependency-tag')` but it didn't work. Thanks

```
<tbody id="target-body">
    <tr id="rhel6-x86_64">
        <td>rhel6-x86_64</td>
        <td>. set_env.sh; make bas</td>
        <td>../cucs-hud_1.5.0_out</td><td>../cucs-hud_1.5.0_log</td>
        <td><input class="dependency-tag"></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
        </td>
     <tr>
```

Comment: It should work: http://jsbin.com/fihurofo/1/edit?js,console . Maybe you are trying to get a reference before the element exists? I hope you read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Did you get any errors? Can you reproduce this in a http://jsfiddle.net ? Your jquery should of worked. Can you explain what did not work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use find method to select the required element

```
$("#rhel6-x86_64").find("input.dependency-tag");
```

Comment: Why should that work, but `$('#rhel6-x86_64 td .dependency-tag')` wouldn't?

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.